# How do you embed a razor EditorFor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor, display-templates

I have a composable web application where the user enters an item number and one of a number of processors is invoked to handle the action based on what type of item it is.  Each "processor" is in a seperate .dll and can be dropped into the application and picked up by the IOC container to allow the site to be extended.

The processors sometimes need to ask for feedback and so pass up an object that is used along with an Html.EditorFor to collect extra information from the user.

My question is whether or not there is a way to embed an EditorFor template in a seperate .dll and have it get picked up in the web application?  Ideally the processor would be able to specify its own EditorFor template so that they don't just use the basic EditorFor template as it is rather lacking.

Comment: Since you don't really explain how this "picked up" process works, or how your system is structured, it's not real easy for us to give you an answer.

Comment: The Dll is dropped in the bin folder and Structurmap is used to pick up all classes that implement the Interface in question.